# configure SSL cert for git svn

Tags: git-svn, ssl-certificate

How can I configure git svn to use my .p12 client cert when connecting to the SVN repo?

If I try to run git svn dcommit, I am asked for my 'Client certificate filename' for each revision and there are a lot of revisions.

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the solution:

added the following lines to my `C:\Users\MyUser\.subversion\servers` file:

```
ssl-authority-files = C:\openSSL\bin\svn_cacert.pem
ssl-client-cert-file = C:\openSSL\bin\my.cert.p12
```

Comment: You forgot and backslash between MyUser and .subversion